# Android App Widget - Button to change TextView content

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I'm a little confused with Android app widgets. I understand that I can create a button to start an activity, but I don't see how I can create a button to edit the text of a TextView inside the widget.
Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

Thanks a lot in advance.

EDIT:
I don't mean for the user to input the new text, I mean for the application to change the text automatically, without any UI (i.e., dialog boxes or activities).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:
OK, so you set a [getBroadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29) PendingIntent on your button with [setOnClickPendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setOnClickPendingIntent%28int,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) and perform your update (or call your update method) with the new text from the receiver. Your [AppWidgetProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html) class can be your receiver (you can catch your intent in [onReceive](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29)), otherwise you create a new class that extends [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

EDIT2 (sample code):

I didn't run/compile this code so hopefully it will not have errors.
This is a simple helper method to get a basic update pending intent with a custom action:

```
public PendingIntent getRefreshPendingIntent(Context context, int appWidgetId){
    Intent intent = new Intent("my.package.ACTION_UPDATE_WIDGET");
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

Catch the custom action in onReceive in your overridden AppWidgetProvider class

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();

    //handle other appwidget actions    

    if (intent.getAction().equals("my.package.ACTION_UPDATE_WIDGET")) {
        //some code here that will update your widget
    }

    //handle other appwidget actions
}
```

You will also need to add an IntentFilter for the custom action to your manifest in the appwidget receiver declaration

```
<receiver
    android:name="my.package.MyWidgetProviderClass"
    android:label="MyWidget">
    <intent-filter>     
        <action android:name="my.package.ACTION_UPDATE_WIDGET"/>
        <!-- other intent filters -->
    </intent-filter>
    <!-- meta data pointing to widget xml file -->
</receiver>
```

Finally you apply the pending intent to your RemoteViews where ever you are building it so when the button is clicked it will send the my.package.ACTION_UPDATE_WIDGET action, which will be caught by your AppWidgetProvider, where you can (or call a method to) perform  your AppWidget update

```
myRemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.id_of_update_button, getRefreshPendingIntent(context, appWidgetId);
```

Comment: I don't mean for the user to update the text, I mean for the application to change the text automatically, without any UI (i.e., dialog boxes or activities). I'll edit my question to be more clear.

Comment: Added some sample code, hopefully there aren't any errors, even so you should get the gist of how to use an onclick PendingIntent

Answer (score 2):

This code updates the widget when you click on it , you can edit it and change the listener to your button :

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
private static final String ACTION_CLICK = "ACTION_CLICK";
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
  int[] appWidgetIds) {

// Get all ids
ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
    MyWidgetProvider.class);
int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
  // Create some random data
  int number = (new Random().nextInt(100));

  RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
      R.layout.widget_layout);
  Log.w("WidgetExample", String.valueOf(number));
  // Set the text
  remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.update, String.valueOf(number));

  // Register an onClickListener
  Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);

  intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
  intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
      0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.update, pendingIntent);
  appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
}
}
}
```

the complete tutorial is [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html).