# How to update view of a widget on button click in android?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-pendingintent

i am developing android widget and i displayed some data on that widget from web service and its working fine.Hear is the code for that.

**CODE**

```
public class WatchWidget extends AppWidgetProvider{


    private static final String TAG = "WatchWidget";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate( Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds ){
        Log.i(TAG, "* onUpdate");


        EBWeaterData ebwd=new EBWeaterData();

        EBWeatreUtils.getWeatherFeeds(context, ebwd, "my url to get data");

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.main);
        RemoteViews newView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.test);

        //get data 
        String day=ebwd.getDay_1()+ebwd.getDay_suffix_1()+" "+ebwd.getDay_name_1();
        String minmaxtemp="Max Temp "+ebwd.getDay_max_temp_1()+"°C "+"Min Temp "+ebwd.getDay_min_temp_1()+"°C";

        //set dat to views
        newView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView_day_name, day);
        newView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView_minmaxtemp, minmaxtemp);  
        newView.setImageViewResource(R.id.ImageView_icon, R.drawable.sunny);

        views.addView(R.id.view_container, newView);      
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,WatchWidget.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, views);

    }

}
```

i have a button on that widget now i want to update the widget view with different values when user clicks on the button.I know I have to do with it pendingIntent like following.

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(context, activitytogetNewdata.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
      views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageView1, pendingIntent);
```

But it will start another activity i dont want to go to anther activity.I just need to do is to update the same widget view with new values after button click.Any Idea??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem of my code.when i going to update my view using pendingintent it will dynamically add view on each and every button click because i have used 2 layout hear so i solved the problem as follows.(i use one layout instead of using two)

**CODE**

```
public class WatchWidget extends AppWidgetProvider{


    private static final String TAG = "WatchWidget";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate( Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds ){
        Log.i(TAG, "* onUpdate");


        EBWeaterData ebwd=new EBWeaterData();

        EBWeatreUtils.getWeatherFeeds(context, ebwd, "my url to get data");


        RemoteViews newView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.test);

        //get data 
        String day=ebwd.getDay_1()+ebwd.getDay_suffix_1()+" "+ebwd.getDay_name_1();
        String minmaxtemp="Max Temp "+ebwd.getDay_max_temp_1()+"°C "+"Min Temp "+ebwd.getDay_min_temp_1()+"°C";

        //set dat to views
        newView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView_day_name, day);
        newView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView_minmaxtemp, minmaxtemp);  
        newView.setImageViewResource(R.id.ImageView_icon, R.drawable.sunny);


        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,WatchWidget.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, newView);

    }
```

Comment: where is your refresh button?

Answer (score 0):

Go through this tutorial.

Visit http://www.developer.com/ws/android/programming/Handling-User-Interaction-with-Android-App-Widgets-3837531.htm

They have solved the problem what you have.

Comment: ok that will update the same view that is fine. but how can i set new values to the view? i mean after button click i want to set values like  newView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView_day_name, day1); insted of day.so i want to detect the button click event.

Comment: Duplicate question. Check the link: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907928/android-app-widget-button-to-change-textview-content

Comment: it sounds like same but it does not address the question i really need to solve.