# Android widget with button and text field on it

Tags: android, android-widget

All I need is to have simple widget, with one Button that will on click update Text field with current time.

I followed several tutorials, but I cannot get it work.

In my case it does not updates Text field... Can you help me to make it work, please?

This was one of my starting points: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_widgets.htm

Java code looks like this (with other XML files):

```
package com.example.myname.widget005;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.nsd.WifiP2pServiceInfo;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;   
import java.util.Date;


/**
 * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
 */
public class Widget005 extends AppWidgetProvider {

    Button btnUpdate;


    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds[i]);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {

        CharSequence widgetText = context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text);
        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget005);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText);

        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

        Date date = new Date();
        String currentTime = date.toString();
        System.out.println("my test => " + currentTime);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Widget005.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.txtInfo, currentTime);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnUpdate, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myname.widget005" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver android:name=".Widget005" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget005_info" />
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

widget005_info.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:minWidth="110dp"
                    android:minHeight="110dp"
                    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
                    android:previewImage="@drawable/example_appwidget_preview"
                    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget005"
                    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
                    android:widgetCategory="home_screen"
                    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/widget005">
</appwidget-provider>
```

widget005.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin"
                android:background="#09C">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/appwidget_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/appwidget_text"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/appwidget_text"
            android:background="#09C"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/txtInfo"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/btnUpdate"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtInfo"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

            />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you add the manifest declaration of the `receiver`? and also the `layout` of the widget

Comment: Ok, you can find all other files in my post

Comment: Here is a previous answer that looks like exactly your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907928/android-app-widget-button-to-change-textview-content